# free host for database

Tags: php, android, database, host

I send my android application data in a table in localhost using phpmyadmin. but when I use my app in an actual device, clearly the data can't be inserted to the localhost table because I don't have a valid IP address. what should I do to have a temporarily valid IP without changing anything?
(I used php code to receive my app's data to save in database)

Comment: you can store it on the phone itself using sqlLite or the like. If you need a public database akin to mysql, you'd need to purchase hosting somewhere

Comment: You might be able to find the one that suits your purpose [here](https://themeisle.com/blog/best-free-website-hosting/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an http tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

example:
`ngrok tcp 3306`

it will expose your tcp port

> Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:16922 ->
> localhost:3306